# Connection to MySQL DB using connection variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database set up with two tables. I have created a sign-up script that connects to a DB through connection variables.. I only specify DBuser DBpassword DBhost and DBname as my parameters.. Do I have to add the specific DB table Im trying to access

Comment: Can you add the code you are using? Any error given to you?

Comment: Do you have a problem with your script or you are asking just out of curiosity? If former post your code.

Answer (score 1):

For connecting to database, it's enough; you don't need to, but for using other mysql statement like `select`, `insert`,... yes you should specify table name